# forward with masking domain, are they using iframe to do that?

Tags: dns, masking, forward

I just wonder how is the forward with masking really works in all the common cases.

I just found out that the manual way of doing it is that just to put this code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>yourname</title>
<meta name="description" content="your description">
<meta name="keywords" content="keyword1, keyword2">
</head>
<frameset rows="100%,0" border="0">
<frame src="http://yourforwardingurl" frameborder="0">
<frame frameborder="0">
</frameset>
</html>
```

does that mean all the provider, registrar (like godaddy) they using the same method?

because if so then I don't know why in the sake of god would I have to wait them do that for me if I can just create a subdomain and put those codes and get it done in a minute rather than wait them activate it for me for 24-48 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have much experience with this but I don't believe that this is a very common way of masking URLs. For one thing, it's very easy to see the actual source of the content. It also seems like it would be a pain to manage. This might be an option if you are hosting a small website and don't have access to the server or a control panel for your domain.

The more common approach is more likely to be something using Apache's [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_proxy.html) ([explained here](http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies)).

Comment: For this application high security isn't needed so a proxy solution is overkill and also the traffic costs money. This is only to provide a easy way to access content with a domain. And such a solution need also work on both ends. Many major hosting companys (including Godaddy) are using such frames. You can manag such things automatically so it's very easy to set up.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the mostly used method is a simple frameset or a iframe (in less cases).

And yes you can simply set up a sub domain with a html file which loads the target in a frame.